# system("program &") equivalent in Windows - launch external app into background

Tags: c++

I need to launch an external application from a Windows C++ app. The external application is "blocking" - it's a console application that doesn't go into background itself but stays in the foreground for its application.

In Linux a simple `&` at the end launches it as a background process when called through `system()`. What is the Windows equivalent of that?

(I know I could just fork the launcher and call plain `system()` from the child, but I'd prefer to avoid the overhead.)

Comment: `cmd /c start ...`. there is no job control in a windows shell like what you want.

Comment: I believe `system("start program")` will do what I need.